# Stream Soundcard to Squeezebox

Tags: audio, streaming, sound-card, squeezebox

I'm looking for a way to transmit what's being played by my soundcard directly to my squeezebox.

The goal is to be able to having anything music that's being played (whether it's from myspace or itunes) stream to the squeezebox.

Running Mac OS X, and Squeezebox Server Version: 7.5.1

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this a while ago, but it was cumbersome. I didn't write down the steps either, so this answer is more to put you in a direction to start with.

I installed [SoundFlower](http://cycling74.com/products/soundflower/), which enables one to pipe sound output from one program as sound input to another. Then I used [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) to act as a MP3 streaming server, to which I connected my SqueezeBox (à la http://10.0.0.42:8080/stream.ogg).

UPDATE:

I now have success running [Nicecast](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/nicecast/) together with SoundFlower. It's easy to use, but costs some money.

Comment: It was probably something along the lines of sound card -- darkice -- icecast -- squeezebox